# Custom url in wordpress

Tags: urls, json

I want to make custom url and handle it from my plugin

Ex:-

```
domain.com/myplugin=endpoint&id=num&..
```

i want to return just json data not template

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a handler function that is called before content is sent to the browser.  Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do, here is a general function that will work:

```
function my_plugin_json_handler(){
    /*First you should check the POST/GET Request for some variable that tells 
    the plugin that this is a request for your json object*/
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['my_triger'] || $_REQUEST['my_trigger'] !== 'some test value')) return;

    //generate your json here

    echo $json; //echo your json to the browser
    exit; //stop executing code (prevents the template from loading)
}
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_json_handler');
```

Exactly where you hook should depend on exactly what you're doing but `init` is generally a safe place.  You should also probably do some kind of check to protect against unauthorized calls to your function using a [`nonce`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Depending on your needs you also may want to consider doing an [ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) call rather than checking `$_REQUEST` on an arbitrary url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
function custom_url_handler() {
    $requestUri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    $urlPattern = '/^\/([\w\d]*\/)?index\.php\?my-trigger\=1(\&|$)/';
    preg_match($urlPattern, $requestUri, $matches);
    if(count($matches) > 0){
        $data = GetData();
        wp_send_json($data);
    }
}

add_action('parse_request', 'custom_url_handler');
```

This will return `$data` as JSON when you hit the `index.php?my-trigger=1` URL (followed by extra url parmeters,  like `index.php?my-trigger=1&param1=4`, or not).